# How to send 102 Processing in Express?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I am setting up a new HTTP server to execute a long command and return the response from that shell command to the client.

I run v4.17.1 of Express. Requests from clients have repeatedly timed out when running this command. (I app.use(cors()) if that makes any difference).

```js
    app.get("/dl", (req, res) => {
        require("child_process").exec("command -url".concat(req.query.url), (err, stdout, stderr) => {
            if (err || stderr) res.status(500).send(`err: ${err.message}, stderr: ${stderr}`);
            res.status(200).send(stdout);
        }
    });
```

Browsers just timeout when I try to run this command because it just takes A LONG TIME. If I can't use 102 Processing that's fine just I would like another solution. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*"If I can't use 102 Processing..."*

Don't use `102 Processing` as it is designed specifically for [WebDAV](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2518). Please check RFC2518 for detail information.

*"I would like another solution"*

You can return `200 OK` for `GET /dl` once the HTTP request is received and the child process is launched, indicating: "Hey, client, I've received your request and started the job successfully":

```
app.get("/dl", (req, res) => {
    require("child_process").exec("command -url".concat(req.query.url));
    res.status(200).end();
});
```

Then, in the child process, save the execution result somewhere (in a file, in DB etc.), and mapping the result to the query url:

```
query url A --> child process result A
query url B --> child process result B
query url C --> child process failed information
```

In client side, after receive `200 OK` for `GET /dl` request, start a poll -- sending request to server every 5 seconds (or whatever time interval you need), with the previous success query url as parameter, trying to get its result in the above mapping. It would be:

- If the result is found in the above mapping, client get what it want, and stop the poll.
- If nothing is found in the above mapping, client keeps polling after another 5 seconds.
- If failed information is found, or polling is timeout, client give up, stop the poll, and display the error message.

Answer (score 2):

I'd suggest not using an HTTP 102.  You can read more about why: https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/316211/79958

I'd also **STRONGLY** recommend against your current logic using a query parameter.  Someone could inject commands that would be executed on the server.